# How to convert *.3OXZ CAD files to *.STL?

Tags: cad

We are using one dental scanner (Vitality Scanner)

[image: Vitality Scanner]

and the output format is in 3doxz Format,So we need to change it to stl for some analyzing on it, So i need to find out any software for this CAD format Converting.

For example one of it's 3DOXZ Format is here:

[3DOXZ CAD Example](https://www.4shared.com/get/YjEgn_8Qei/51832_170524101342.html)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you sure the format can be converted to STL.  Most likely the format is some kind of poit cloud or possibly voxel data (Due to nature of sensor). None of which will not turn to stl without some heavy processing.

Comment: yes it could be converted to stl